# "chess problem" software (free/paid) to download for PC?

Tags: software

I tried one a while back but it was quite elementary, it had a few thousand problems but did not give detailed answers, just one single move as correct and that's it!

I do play Chesstempo sometimes but don't always have internet connection and also I want something I can have on my computer if I'm outside or somewhere there is no connection so I can do that, one with range of problems, not just tactics but like endgame stuff too that sometimes is more tough to calculate than tactic. Any programs you're aware of?

Edit: I only saw a thread on training particular chess tactics but that's not what I'm looking for, just chess problems of all sorts.

Answer (score 4):

LucasChess is the best free software out there. You can add any engine you like and you can analyze your games with multiple engines. It also has a training mode for tactics, openings, and endgame.

I highly recommend it. I recommended it to a friend who loved it so much that he hardly uses his Chessmaster these days.

Here's the link:

**https://www-lucaschess.rhcloud.com/**

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking about chess composition, i.e. mate problems in n moves with thematic variations, you need a software specialized in the problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_for_handling_chess_problems

Of course, I have a preference for the one I designed and developed: [Problemist](http://www.sudoktor.com/prb/) [www.problemist.com](http://www.problemist.com).

Comment: Welcome!   Nice to see that Problemist still is alive!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need is the problem database (e.g. a PGN file containing the variations). There are many chess programs that have built-in training modes, i.e. they'll ask you to find the next move.
A free program supporting this is [SCID](http://scid.sourceforge.net/). Any variations can be in the database (not just tactics).

Answer (score 0):

CT-Art has great tactics that you can buy for like $35. It runs through this program called Peshk@. Its full of tons and tons of tactics that are organized thematically (forks - split into knight forks, pawn forks, etc. - , pins, destroying the defense). After working through some thematically you can 'test' and pick to shuffle together the tactics.